# I need a MySQL query for find the total count from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find the total number of occurrence of a specific values in columns.

**eg:**

In the below image of my mysql table structure i have fields like `essc_a1`, `essc_a2` ... `essc_a10`.

`a1` to `a10` entries coming from a group of ten questions.I need to find the number of occurrence of a value (for eg:  "eg" or "S") in a1 to a10 columns.

I tried the following query but not working for me.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(essc_a1,essc_a2,...,essc_a10) as count 
FROM 
    employee_satisfaction_survey_checklist 
GROUP BY 
    essc_a1, essc_a2,..., essc_a10 
WHERE
    essc_a1 LIKE '% es %' 
    OR essc_a2 LIKE '% es %' 
    OR .... essc_a10 LIKE '% es %';
```

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: from what i see....u DEFINITELY need to redesign your schema!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's ugly, but it can be done. Would make a lot more sense to have a table of questions and a table with a single row for each response to each a question, but if you can't do that you can do something like this, extending the SUM to include all 10 columns:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(essc_a1 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a2 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0))
FROM employee_satisfaction_survey_checklist
```

Comment: no matter the method is ,we need a solution ! :) i tried your method and its working for me. SELECT SUM(IF(essc_a1 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a2 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a3 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a4 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a5 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a6 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a7 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a8 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a9 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0) + IF(essc_a10 LIKE '%es%', 1, 0)) 
FROM employee_satisfaction_survey_checklist

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to accept the answer if it's working for you :)